# how much is the data transfer limit for a VM e2-small instance in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to know for sure. How much is the data transfer limit for a VM e2-small instance? Since nowhere is there a meter that indicates the amount of GB transferred or what remains to be transferred.

[e2-small VM Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDG12.png)

Comment: SO is for programming question so maybe your questions better fits in ServerFault

Answer (score 1):

There is no limits. The ingress is free, you have to pay for the egress (inter-region or going to the internet).

You have network [bandwidth soft limit](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines#e2_limitations): 1 Gbps

That's all

Comment: Typo: **egress is free** should be **ingress is free**.

Comment: Good catch @JohnHanley. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "soft limit"?
What happens when that limit is exceeded?
Does the VM no longer work or is an additional fee charged for each GB exceeded?

Comment: It's soft because you can temporarily burst that limit in peak, but not in a sustainable traffic. If you reach that limit, your traffic is throttle.

Comment: I understand that one thing is a bandwidth limit and another is "transfer limit" which is the reason for my query. I think that the bandwidth limit is a limit for what can be transferred at a peak moment, but the transfer limit to which I refer is the accumulated amount of data that is transmitted in a certain amount of time, for example, in a month. In IBM Cloud my monthly limit is 250GB/Monthly, in Digital Ocean it is 4TB/Monthly. Etc.

Comment: I'm not aware about that on Google Cloud, the limit is your wallet!